# The way to import modules into scrapy spiders once?

Tags: python, scrapy

every time I adding a new spider.py to scrapy, I need to import some modules, for example:

```
from __future__ import division
from extruct.w3cmicrodata import MicrodataExtractor
from extruct.jsonld import JsonLdExtractor
import scrapy
import re
import logging
from pprint import pprint
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from urlparse import urlparse
import tldextract
import json
....
```

It's very boring that add these modules every time.

I'm new to python, Is there a way to import these things once then don't need to import them for each spider file? Just like php.

Answer (score 3):

You can put all these imports to a module (myimports.py) and then run `from .myimports import *`, but this is a bad practice - in Python such implicit imports are highly discouraged because they make code less maintainable.

If you have common imports then maybe there is some common code in these spiders, and you can extract it to a library of utility functions, or to a base spider class?

You can also use [scrapy genspider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#std:command-genspider) command and a custom spider template. Create a folder with the following structure:

```
mytemplates
  spiders
    myspider.tmpl
```

Then set your project's [TEMPLATES_DIR](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?#templates-dir) option to this folder, put the spider template (just a file with starter Python code) in `myspider.tmpl` file.

Currently `name` and `domain` are required `genspider` arguments; you can use these variables in the template, e.g.

```
import scrapy
# your long imports list

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "$name"
    allowed_domains = ["$domain"]
    start_urls = ['http://$domain/']

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

Then run `scrapy genspider --list` to check that your template is available, then run `scrapy genspider -t myspider <spider-name> <domain-to-crawl>`.

There are also other, more versatile template generation utilities - take a look at [cookiecutter](http://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

In my opinion the way to go is to extract common code, this should help with reducing import list; code generation is a worse solution, and a module with all imports is an awful solution, it is the worst.

Don't worry too much about long list of imports, it is common in Python to have such lists of imports at the top of the file, and that's for good - you can see where a function or a class came from, it makes debugging easier.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I came from PHP world, I think I need some time to learn the zen of Python:)